# That I have wrong with this code? Trying to show a datepicker on a edittext

Tags: android

That I have wrong with this code?
I date indicates that the **variable has to be marked as final**, but if I do it still does not work, shoot me error: **Insert app indexed code api.**
I'm trying that through a EditText I display a datepicker

```
final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
```

Here code

```
package com.example.cesar.mybankaccess.view;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.example.cesar.mybankaccess.R;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

public class PromocionesFormulario extends AppCompatActivity{
    Calendar myCalendar;
    EditText fechaInicio;
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_promociones_formulario);
        fechaInicio = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fechaInicio);
        myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                                  int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                updateLabel();
            }
        };
        fechaInicio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new DatePickerDialog(PromocionesFormulario.class, date, myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            }
        });
    }


    private void updateLabel() {

        String myFormat = "MM/dd/yy"; //In which you need put here
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);

        fechaInicio.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date` final. And in,

```
new DatePickerDialog(PromocionesFormulario.class, date, myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
    myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
```

Pass `PromocionesFormulario.this` instead of `PromocionesFormulario.class`.

The problem here is, the type of `PromocionesFormulario.class` is `Class`. But `new DatePickerDialog()` requires `Context` object as first parameter.

Comment: Awesome. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

As Msp mentioned, you also need to change that. Context is given with `.this`, 
not `.class`

---

If you're trying to make the object final, clear this line:

```
 DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() { //...
```

and make it:

```
date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() { //...
```

then update your initialization, like:

```
final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date;
```

other than that, your question is not obvious.